# Command substitution as target for I/O redirection

Tags: bash, io-redirection, command-substitution

I was trying to have the output of a command as a target of redirection like this:

```
echo .envrc >> $(git config --global core.excludesfile)
```

But I get this error instead, where `~/.gitignore_global` is the output of `git config --global core.excludesfile`.

```
bash: ~/.gitignore_global: No such file or directory
```

I was able to get it working using `eval`:

```
eval "echo .envrc >> $(git config --global core.excludesfile)"
```

Why didn't it work previously and is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the global git config contains a literal `~` (tilde) which is not interpreted by the shell when emitted as the result of a command substitution. Your global git config likely contains the following:

```
[core]
    excludesfile = ~/.gitignore_global
```

Your first command is the equivalent of the following construct, which uses single quotes to prevent shell interpretation of the `~` character:

```
echo .envrc >> '~/.gitignore_global'
```

Using `eval` fixes this because it causes (re-)intepretation of its string argument (in this case, the exact line above), including tilde expansion, which results in the expected command:

```
echo .envrc >> /home/your_user/.gitignore_global
```

Another way to fix this is to ensure the value in your global git config is a full path:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

In this case, the shell will expand `~` to `/home/your_user`, so the contents of your global git config file will read something like:

```
[core]
    excludesfile = /home/your_user/.gitignore_global
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better not to use tildas like this outside of an interactive shell. (Shell scripts usually use the `$HOME` environment variable). If you must, the better way is to do the expansion safely and that isn't easy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash/29310477#29310477

If it's just a one-time command, and you know what `git config --global core.excludesfile` evaluates to and that it's safe to eval that, then your solution is fine.